# Show dynamic content with "Show More" button with minimum 3 lines of content visible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to show 3 lines of dynamic content which may include Heading, Paragraph or span (without cutting of any content) and by clicking on "Show More" button it will show all the content inside.
Here is the code example: Fix height is not solution here which I am using in this example. Please suggest the better work around. Thanks

```js
$('.show-btn').on('click', function(){
$('.show-less').css("max-height" , "initial");
});
```

```css
.show-less 
{
    max-height: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 25px;
    transition: all 1s;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show-less" class="show-less">
<p>hi, this is a test description.</p>
<h2>hi, this is a test description.</h2>
<p>hi, this is a test description.</p>
<p>hi, this is a test description.</p>
<h2>hi, this is a test description.</h2>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show-btn">Show More</a>
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_read_more) will solve your problem.

Comment: No it does not help here as It is the dynamic content with variety of tags.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this?

HTML :

```
<div class="box">
      <h2>hi, this is a test description.</h2>
      <p>hi, this is a test description.</p>
      <p>hi, this is a test description.</p>
    
      <p>hi, this is a test description.</p>
      <h2>hi, this is a test description.</h2>
</div>
    
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="show-btn">Show More/Less</a>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  max-height: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 13px !important;
  line-height: 25px !important;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  transition: all 1s;
  clear: both;
}

.box--more-mode {
  max-height: initial;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".show-btn").on("click", function () {
  $(".box").toggleClass("box--more-mode");
});
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/ysilavi/pen/QWMyLQo)

Comment: No it won't help as you have given static max-height which is not okay with dynamic content which may contains only headings or Ul li or any other tags which can be of different heights.

Comment: so, what about extra div, like this? https://codepen.io/ysilavi/pen/QWMyLQo

Comment: This is the dynamic content as I mentioned in my question.